# How to update node values in XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2008, ssis

I have to update an original XML file with modified values. Below is my sample XML file:

```
<request>
<facility>
<alternateIDs>
            <alternateID code="ALT8">11111111</alternateID>
            <alternateID code="ALT12">111111111</alternateID>
            <alternateID code="ALT">1111111111</alternateID>
            <alternateID code="ALT1">11111111</alternateID>
            <alternateID code="ALT9">11111111</alternateID>
            <alternateID code="ALT3">111111111</alternateID>
</alternateIDs>
</facility>
</request>
```

Now I want to look for `alternateID code="ALT"` and change its value to `00000000`. My final file should look like:

```
<request>
<facility>
<alternateIDs>
            <alternateID code="ALT8">11111111</alternateID>
            <alternateID code="ALT12">111111111</alternateID>
            <alternateID code="ALT">00000000</alternateID>
            <alternateID code="ALT1">11111111</alternateID>
            <alternateID code="ALT9">11111111</alternateID>
            <alternateID code="ALT3">111111111</alternateID>
</alternateIDs>
</facility>
</request>
```

How can I achieve this using `XElement` and `XAttributes`? I am not familiar with XML and C#. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!

```
public static void ReplaceCode()
     {
        var root = new XmlDocument();
         root.Load(@"C:\data.xml");

        foreach (XmlNode e in root.GetElementsByTagName("alternateID"))
        {
            if (e.Attributes["code"].Value.Equals("ALT"))
            {
                e.FirstChild.Value = "00000000"; // FirstChild because the inner node is actually the inner text, yeah XmlNode is weird.
                break;
            }
        }
        root.Save(@"C:\data.xml");
    }
```

Ask me anything about it and I can clarify. :)

Comment: thank you very much.. i got it!! :-).. only thing is once the value gets set to 0000000, i want to come out of the loop. but break here, actually take the control to the last line in the script and not immediate line after the loop.

Comment: Awesome! glad I could help. If you think it was good you should pay it forward and +1 the answer so others can see. :) I just went through this same problem so I just had to respond. hahahaha

Comment: The arrows on left side. Cheers.

Comment: thanks!! I did it.. Somehow not able to save the changes in the file.. when I check root variable in debug mode values are still not updated

Comment: Check the file location, would your system have permission to edit a file there? Also is it a service ? That would mess it up for sure. I know how to fix that as well though

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication34
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement alt = doc.Descendants("alternateID").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("code") == "ALT").FirstOrDefault();
            alt.Value = "00000000";

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: i cannot use linq XML. i am trying using XMLdocument, XML element but I am missing something..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non Linq way of doing it, although linq is much cleaner if you know how to read it.

```
public static void ReplaceCode()
     {
        var root = XElement.Load(@"C:\data.xml");
        foreach (var e in root.Descendants("alternateID"))
        {
            if (!e.Attribute("code").Value.Equals("ALT")) continue;
            e.Value = "00000000";
            break;
        }
        root.Save(@"C:\data.xml");
    }
```

Comment: for me somehow Xelement, Xdocument are disabled and i am only able to use XMLelement, XMLDocument etc.

Comment: Not a problem, my second answer that I just posted solves that. I'm keeping this answer up for others benefit. It goes nicely beside jdwengs sweet linq statement.